# Downloading file from POST request with Elm

Tags: post, download, elm

I'm in the position that I have an HTTP POST endpoint `/render` that returns a PDF document, and would like to present a button/link to the user that will cause this document to be downloaded and saved to a file without navigating away from my Elm app.

Ideally the POST will accept a `text/plain` body with a custom format, but I could rework the endpoint to accept `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I can download the raw data to the Elm app successfully as follows, but I'm at a loss for how to save the file to disk.

```
import Http

render : String -> Http.Request String
render body =
  Http.request
    { method = "POST"
    , headers = []
    , url = "/render"
    , body = Http.stringBody "text/plain" body
    , expect = expectString
    , timeout = Nothing
    , withCredentials = False
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting on the server side the [Content-Disposition response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) so that the PDF will be sent as an attachment?  That should give the browser instructions to allow user to either save the file or show it. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: It was my understanding that Elm sends requests through XMLHttpRequest and that the responses would not trigger normal browser download behaviour automatically. But I'll admit that I have not tried this explicitly. Will give it a shot, thank you.

Comment: I think you are right and it won't work with XHR. So, I had misunderstood the problem. Html 5 seems to have brought us some help in this area, but can't really say how [these JS tricks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) can be used in Elm.

Answer (score 4):

I did it using `expectBytes` rather then `expectString`
so my code is

```
import Bytes exposing (Bytes)
import File.Download as Download

Msg = .. | FormUploaded (Result Http.Error Bytes)

Http.post
        { url = "/passports"
        , body =
            Http.multipartBody...
        , expect = Http.expectBytesResponse FormUploaded (resolve Ok)
        }


downloadPdf : Bytes -> Cmd msg
downloadPdf pdfContent =
    Download.bytes "form.pdf" "application/pdf" pdfContent

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update model =
...
    FormUploaded (Ok response) ->
            ( model, downloadPdf response )
    FormUploaded (Err err) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

-- this helper function copied from https://github.com/elm/http/blob/2.0.0/src/Http.elm#L514-L521
resolve : (body -> Result String a) -> Http.Response body -> Result Http.Error a
resolve toResult response =
    case response of
        BadUrl_ url ->
            Err (BadUrl url)

        Timeout_ ->
            Err Timeout

        NetworkError_ ->
            Err NetworkError

        BadStatus_ metadata _ ->
            Err (BadStatus metadata.statusCode)

        GoodStatus_ _ body ->
            Result.mapError BadBody (toResult body)
```

it's not ideal but works

PS: I got help from Elm Slack Channel https://elmlang.slack.com/